# DUDA URGENTE PORFAVOR

Tags: python, dataframe

Hola muy buenas el ejercicio que estoy intentando resolver se trata de pasar de un `Dataframe` como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al siguiente pero con estas caracterísiticas:
Notas importantes sobre el `DataFrame` **`resultado`**:

- El índice del `DataFrame` tendrá los nombres de los modelos, y sólo
  deben aparecer aquellos para los que al menos un usuario haya pagado.
  Es decir que no deben aparecer los modelos que hayan sido siempre
  gratuitos.
- Los modelos deben aparecer en orden alfabético de acuerdo a su nombre.
- Todos los números que no sean enteros deben aparecer redondeados a dos cifras decimales.

Como la desviación estándar no se puede calcular cuando haya
sólo un dato, en lugar de NaN debe aparecer 0.0 en el resultado.
Obteniendo el `Dataframe` un resultado de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He utilizado este código pero siempre me acaba dando una cantidad más de lo debido o un comentario menos:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Es mejor recibir un diccionario y crear el dataframe adentro de tu función
def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:dict)->pd.DataFrame:
    # Paso 1: cargar los datos
    df = pd.DataFrame(descargas)
    
    # TRUE y FALSE son strings por lo que hay que convertirlos a booleanos
    # Convertir TRUE a True y FALSE a False
    df['COMENTARIO'] = df['COMENTARIO'].map({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
    df['COMENTARIO'].replace({True: 1, False: 0})
    
    # Paso 3: calcular las estadísticas
    agg_dict = {
        "PAGO": ["count", "mean", "max", "min"],
        "ESTRELLAS": ["mean", "std"],
        # Reemplazamos count por sum
        "COMENTARIO": ["count"]
    }
    stats = df.groupby('MODELO').agg(agg_dict)
    # Paso 4: crear el DataFrame resultado
    resultado = pd.DataFrame({
        "CANTIDAD": stats["PAGO"]["count"],
        "PROMEDIO": stats["PAGO"]["mean"].round(2),
        "MAXIMO": stats["PAGO"]["max"].round(2),
        "MINIMO": stats["PAGO"]["min"].round(2),
        "ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["mean"].round(2),
        "DESV. ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["std"].round(2),
        "COMENTARIOS": stats["COMENTARIO"]["count"]
    }, index=stats.index)
    indices_promedio_cero = resultado[resultado["PROMEDIO"] == 0].index
    resultado = resultado.drop(indices_promedio_cero)
    resultado = resultado.fillna(0.0)
    
       
    
    # Ordenar los resultados alfabéticamente por nombre de modelo
    resultado = resultado.sort_index()
    
    return resultado
```

Comment: Bienvenido. El título de cualquier artículo es tan importante e incluso más que su contenido. Lo primero que ves es el título. ¿Crees que alguien compraría un libro que se llame **DUDA, URGENTE POR FAVOR**? Además está mal visto publicar preguntas **urgentes**. Ninguna pregunta es más importante que otra.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el resultado esperado, para que quienes respondan puedan confirmar la validez de la respuesta.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Un mal título no es motivo de cierre valido

Comment: @Yussef la caja de comentarios no es el lugar para esas discusiones, favor de plantear el tema en meta donde ya se han tratado algunos casos similares.

Answer (score 0):

No es la opción más elegante (se que existe)... se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd


def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:dict)->pd.DataFrame:
  '''Descripción detallada de la función'''

  if isinstance(descargas, dict):
    # Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=descargas, orient='columns')

    # Para los (pagos==0) cambiamos el cero (0) por NaN
    df['Modelo']= df['Modelo'].where(df['Pago']>0)
    # Eliminamos los valores NaN
    df = df.drop('Usuario', axis=1).dropna()

    ### Agrupamos por 'Modelo' y calculamos: (minimos, maximos, promedios,
    # desviaciones std) de las columnas ('Pago' 'Estrellas' 'Comentario')
    pago = df[['Modelo', 'Pago']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['count','mean','max', 'min']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    # Eliminamos el nivel superior creado en las columnas
    pago.columns = pago.columns.droplevel()
    # Cambiamos el nombre de las columnas
    pago.columns = ['CANTIDAD', 'PROMEDIO', 'MAXIMO', 'MINIMO']

    
    estrellas = df[['Modelo', 'Estrellas']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['max','std']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    estrellas.columns = estrellas.columns.droplevel()
    estrellas.columns = ['ESTRELLAS', 'DEV.ESTRELLAS']

    comentarios = df[['Modelo', 'Comentario']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['sum']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    comentarios.columns = comentarios.columns.droplevel()
    comentarios.columns = ['COMENTARIOS']
    
    # Concatenomos lo dataframes «pago», «estrellas» y «comentarios» 
    df = pd.concat([pago, estrellas, comentarios], axis=1)

     
    return df

  raise TypeError( "‼\n\n  Tipo de parametro incorrecto...\n"\
                      f"\n\t«descargas» es:        {str(type(descargas))} ✘"\
                       "\n\t«descargas» debe ser:  <class 'dict'> ✔\n")





def main():
  '''Funcion principal'''
  diccionario = { 'Modelo': ['Bus urbano #27','Silla tipo bar','Piano','Fuente con flores','Bus urbano #27','Puesto de Yogurt','Playground','Bus urbano #27'],
                 'Usuario': ['Ted Mosby','Art Vandelay','Art Vandelay','Michael','Mark Brendanawicz','Michael','LeCorbusier_2020',''],
                 'Pago': [24.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0],
                 'Estrellas': [5, 3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
                 'Comentario': [True]+[False]*2+[True]*5 }
  
  calcular_estadisticas(diccionario)





if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

La función retornaría:

```
                CANTIDAD  PROMEDIO  MAXIMO  MINIMO  ESTRELLAS  DEV.ESTRELLAS  COMENTARIOS
Modelo                                                                                   
Bus urbano #27         2    18.495   24.99   12.00        5.0       0.707107            2
Piano                  1     4.990    4.99    4.99        3.5       0.000000            0
Playground             1    14.000   14.00   14.00        4.5       0.000000            1
Silla tipo bar         1     4.990    4.99    4.99        3.5       0.000000            0
```

Otra opción (la cual me parece mas refinada) seria...

```
import pandas as pd


diccionario = { 'Modelo': ['Bus urbano #27','Silla tipo bar','Piano','Fuente con flores','Bus urbano #27','Puesto de Yogurt','Playground','Bus urbano #27'],
                 'Usuario': ['Ted Mosby','Art Vandelay','Art Vandelay','Michael','Mark Brendanawicz','Michael','LeCorbusier_2020',''],
                 'Pago': [24.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0],
                 'Estrellas': [5, 3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
                 'Comentario': [True]+[False]*2+[True]*5 }


# Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=diccionario, orient='columns')

# Para los (pagos==0) cambiamos el cero (0) por NaN
df['Modelo']= df['Modelo'].where(df['Pago']>0)
# Eliminamos los valores NaN
df = df.drop('Usuario', axis=1).dropna()


### Agrupamos por 'Modelo' y calculamos: (minimos, maximos, promedios,
# desviaciones std) de las columnas ('Pago' 'Estrellas' 'Comentario')
df = df.groupby('Modelo').agg(['count','min', 'max','mean','std']).fillna(0).sort_index()
```

Después eliminas las columnas innecesarias con:

```
df.drop(('Pago', 'std'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(('Pago', 'sum'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Si es exactamente la misma respuesta, es porque es exactamente la misma pregunta!!!